# Where can I find better documentation for x3dom?

Tags: x3dom

I have been searching the web for documentation for x3dom, and all I can find is the documentation on their website which is, unfortunately, not that helpful. I am looking for something that explains the attributes for all the elements (specifically, rotation, translate, gradients for the different color attributes, etc...).

Or, maybe even a site that had tutorials on how to do basic and advanced programming with x3dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the moment you have to get into the actual source on github here:

https://github.com/x3dom/x3dom

as well join the mail lists, i try to answer questions on there as well as here.

today they mentioned using sphinx to generate better docs from the source code 
until then youll have to do the legwork yourself

Answer (score 0):

X3DOM basically translates X3D into WebGL, so what you need is documentation on X3D (aka X3D node reference).  There is a lot of documentation on X3D.  Keep in mind that X3DOM does not support all X3D nodes.

Moreover, X3D is basically VRML with XML syntax.  So you can use a VRML documentation, if you keep in mind that the syntax is different.  Again, there is a lot of documentation on VRML.

My favorite VRML documentation, which I use for my X3DOM work:

http://www.lighthouse3d.com/vrml/tutorial/